# Parse-Server signUp invalidsessiontoken error

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I'm getting an invalidsessiontoken error when calling`user.signUp()`.
The process is I call my cloud code function to create a new user and send back the sessionToken to become that user on client side.
Cloud Code:

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("firstname", fname);
user.set("lastname", lname);
user.set("birthdate", birthdate);
user.set("username", email);
user.set("email", email);
user.set("password", pass);
user.set("emailVerified", false);
user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user){
        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
        acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
        user.setACL(acl);
        user.save(null, {
            useMasterKey: true
        }).then(function(user){
            sendEmailVerification(user.get("email"), function(error){
                if(error){
                    console.log("USER SENDEMAILVERIFICATION ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    sendMsg(res, error.code, error.message);
                    return;
                }
                sendMsg(res, 200, user.getSessionToken());
            });
        }, function(error){
            console.log("USER SAVE ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            sendMsg(res, error.code, error.message);
        });
    }, error: function(user, error){
        console.log("USER SIGNUP ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
        sendMsg(res, error.code, error.message);
    }
});
```

invalidsessiontoken always occurs at USER SIGNUP ERROR.
I'm not sure what causes this because I don't think there should even be a session token at that moment. When an invalidsessiontoken error is found on client side I try to call logout and afterwards the cloud code again but it causes an infinite loop.

Comment: why dont you do it on client side?
can you post you client side when you use the become method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use user.signUp, after the user is created it connect the user.
The problem in this case that this is not a good idea to connect in cloud code.

Their is a difference from cloud code in regular parse. If you connect in one function and another user run cloud function, you still connect with the first user. 
From the same reason their is no `Parse.User.current()` in cloud code.

I think that the best option would be signup from the client side. You dont have to pass the session token and use the `become` function.

If you want to check the values use `beforesave` trigger, and then decide if create or not create the user.

Comment: Thank you @Alon I will move signup to client side in a bit when i go back to my computer to test

Comment: One reason I decided to call signUp in cloud code though is because it's more secure

Comment: Why? Look at my edit to the answer, use`beforesave` trigger

Comment: This does seem to work better, I don't seem to get that error anymore.